# Sql: how to select created by (count) when day is Monday and month is January?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to `select created_by="James"`  (count)  when day is Monday and month is January.

Hot to achieve it?
Could you please help me showing some queries examples?

Thanks,

Nicola

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the reference manual regarding date and time functions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

I think your query should look similar to this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM your_table
WHERE created_by = "James"
AND MONTH(your_date_column) = 1
And DAYNAME(your_date_column) = "Monday"
```

to get the counts for the different days of the week you need to group by dayname:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count,
       DAYNAME(your_date_column) AS dayname
FROM your_table
WHERE created_by = "James"
AND MONTH(your_date_column) = 1
GROUP BY DAYNAME(your_date_column)
```